# Safari 15, Reactjs: Unhandled Rejection (InvalidAccessError): getDisplayMedia must be called from a user gesture handler in Safari MacOs

Tags: reactjs, button, safari, gesture, get-display-media

I have been Implementing this Code asking for User Display Media, this works well getting the User  Display Media on almost every browser like Chrome, Firefox, or Edge,... But on Safari 15 MacOs, and just Safari, I received this error: "Unhandled Rejection (InvalidAccessError): getDisplayMedia must be called from a user gesture handler in Safari macOS".

As far as I know, a User Gesture is counted as a Button click.

Here is the code for the function handleAllowRecord asking for screen sharing and camera:

```
const handleAllowRecord = async () => {
        const mediaDevices = navigator.mediaDevices as any;

        if (
            /(android|bb\d+|meego).+mobile|avantgo|bada\/|blackberry|blazer|compal|elaine|fennec|hiptop|iemobile|ip(hone|od)|ipad|iris|kindle|Android|Silk|lge |maemo|midp|mmp|netfront|opera m(ob|in)i|palm( os)?|phone|p(ixi|re)\/|plucker|pocket|psp|series(4|6)0|symbian|treo|up\.(browser|link)|vodafone|wap|windows (ce|phone)|xda|xiino/i.test(
                navigator.userAgent
            ) ||
            /1207|6310|6590|3gso|4thp|50[1-6]i|770s|802s|a wa|abac|ac(er|oo|s\-)|ai(ko|rn)|al(av|ca|co)|amoi|an(ex|ny|yw)|aptu|ar(ch|go)|as(te|us)|attw|au(di|\-m|r |s )|avan|be(ck|ll|nq)|bi(lb|rd)|bl(ac|az)|br(e|v)w|bumb|bw\-(n|u)|c55\/|capi|ccwa|cdm\-|cell|chtm|cldc|cmd\-|co(mp|nd)|craw|da(it|ll|ng)|dbte|dc\-s|devi|dica|dmob|do(c|p)o|ds(12|\-d)|el(49|ai)|em(l2|ul)|er(ic|k0)|esl8|ez([4-7]0|os|wa|ze)|fetc|fly(\-|_)|g1 u|g560|gene|gf\-5|g\-mo|go(\.w|od)|gr(ad|un)|haie|hcit|hd\-(m|p|t)|hei\-|hi(pt|ta)|hp( i|ip)|hs\-c|ht(c(\-| |_|a|g|p|s|t)|tp)|hu(aw|tc)|i\-(20|go|ma)|i230|iac( |\-|\/)|ibro|idea|ig01|ikom|im1k|inno|ipaq|iris|ja(t|v)a|jbro|jemu|jigs|kddi|keji|kgt( |\/)|klon|kpt |kwc\-|kyo(c|k)|le(no|xi)|lg( g|\/(k|l|u)|50|54|\-[a-w])|libw|lynx|m1\-w|m3ga|m50\/|ma(te|ui|xo)|mc(01|21|ca)|m\-cr|me(rc|ri)|mi(o8|oa|ts)|mmef|mo(01|02|bi|de|do|t(\-| |o|v)|zz)|mt(50|p1|v )|mwbp|mywa|n10[0-2]|n20[2-3]|n30(0|2)|n50(0|2|5)|n7(0(0|1)|10)|ne((c|m)\-|on|tf|wf|wg|wt)|nok(6|i)|nzph|o2im|op(ti|wv)|oran|owg1|p800|pan(a|d|t)|pdxg|pg(13|\-([1-8]|c))|phil|pire|pl(ay|uc)|pn\-2|po(ck|rt|se)|prox|psio|pt\-g|qa\-a|qc(07|12|21|32|60|\-[2-7]|i\-)|qtek|r380|r600|raks|rim9|ro(ve|zo)|s55\/|sa(ge|ma|mm|ms|ny|va)|sc(01|h\-|oo|p\-)|sdk\/|se(c(\-|0|1)|47|mc|nd|ri)|sgh\-|shar|sie(\-|m)|sk\-0|sl(45|id)|sm(al|ar|b3|it|t5)|so(ft|ny)|sp(01|h\-|v\-|v )|sy(01|mb)|t2(18|50)|t6(00|10|18)|ta(gt|lk)|tcl\-|tdg\-|tel(i|m)|tim\-|t\-mo|to(pl|sh)|ts(70|m\-|m3|m5)|tx\-9|up(\.b|g1|si)|utst|v400|v750|veri|vi(rg|te)|vk(40|5[0-3]|\-v)|vm40|voda|vulc|vx(52|53|60|61|70|80|81|83|85|98)|w3c(\-| )|webc|whit|wi(g |nc|nw)|wmlb|wonu|x700|yas\-|your|zeto|zte\-/i.test(
                navigator.userAgent.substr(0, 4)
            )
        ) {
            const webcamShare = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });

            setMediaStream(webcamShare);
            setScreenStream(webcamShare);
        } else {
            const webcamShare = await mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true, video: true });
            const screenStreamVideoOnly = await mediaDevices.getDisplayMedia({ video: true });
            const [webcamAudioTrack] = webcamShare.getAudioTracks();
            const [screenVideoTrack] = screenStreamVideoOnly.getVideoTracks();
            const VideoStreamwithAudio = new MediaStream([webcamAudioTrack, screenVideoTrack]);

            setMediaStream(webcamShare);
            setScreenStream(VideoStreamwithAudio);
        }
        setButtonLoading(true);
        setOpenRecordDialog(true);
    };
```

Then I bind this Function on an onClick handler of a Material UI Button

```
                                        <Button
                                            color="primary"
                                            size="large"
                                            variant="contained"
                                            onClick={handleAllowRecord}
                                            disabled={!agreeCamAndMic ||!agreeTermAndPrivacy || buttonLoading}
                                            // onClick={() => handleAllowRecord()}
                                        >
                                            Continue
                                        </Button>
```

Why does this code throw a gesture handler error? And any ideas on how I can implement the fix? Thank you very much

P.S: I see that Google Hangouts is doing screen-sharing on Safari 15 nicely without any problems. I guess there are alternative ways to do screen sharings rather than getDisplayMedia()?